# how to fetch array/property from an object array in swift

Tags: swift3

I got a class like this :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class ProductDetailsJSON {

var _product_title: String?
var _description: String?
var _regular_price: String?
var _sale_price: String?
var _product_currency: String?
var _sizes:[String] = [String]()
var _color: [String] = [String]()
var _image: [URL] = [URL]()

required init?(items: JSON){

    self._product_title = items["product_title"].stringValue
    self._description = items["description"].stringValue
    self._regular_price = items["regular_price"].stringValue
    self._sale_price = items["sale_price"].stringValue
    self._product_currency = items["product_currency"].stringValue

    if let post_SizeArray = items["size"].array {
        for item in post_SizeArray {
            if let size = item["size_data"].string {
                self._sizes.append(size)
            }
        }
    }

    if let post_ColorArray = items["color"].array {
        for item in post_ColorArray {
            if let color = item["color_data"].string {
                self._color.append(color)
            }
        }
    }

    if let post_imgArray = items["gallery"].array {
        for item in post_imgArray {
            if let postUrl = item["guid"].URL {
                self._image.append(postUrl)
            }
        }
    }

}


}
```

I have declared an array of **ProductDetailsJSON** in a **viewController** . I want to extract the **_product_title**, **_description** etc in various **label**s and need to extract the **_sizes**, **_color** and append in some **array** . I am struggling with these. I can populate a **tableView** with **_image** array but I need to show other values outside a **tableView** . Thank you .